# Can you capture enemy starbases?

Tags: galactic-civilizations-3

Is it possible to capture an existing enemy starbase so you can start acquiring the resources it controls without destroying it and building one yourself?

Comment: I'm not sure if you're able to influence flip one (either way, wouldn't work for the Drengin and Altarian). So in that case, I doubt it.

Comment: In Galactic Civilizations 2 it wasn't possible, don't know about 3

Comment: @Flater How are Drengin and Altarian special in this regard (note the answer)? I'm new to this series.

Comment: @DavidHarkness: I forget the name of the trait, but they're immune to culture flips. **Unwaivering**, I think. Which is why the Drengin are so prone to come colonize inside your influence.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is an Ideology in the Benevolent tree, "Enticing" (Prominence III):

[image: All planets and starbases within our Influence join our civilization]

For **starbases**, this seems to be a one-time event that happens when the ideology is selected.

---

You didn't ask about planets, but to avoid confusion: **Planets** can be turned without Enticing, but it takes a lot of time.

[image: Colony is 54% in rebellion]

It took me dozens of turns after this screenshot before the planet finally converted to me. The long time is due to the *Unwaivering* trait of the Drengin.

Comment: To be clear, this is a one-time event that happens when the ideology is selected. Any worlds or starbases that come into your influence (but not owned by you) after selecting the trait will remain with their original owners.

Comment: @RavenDreamer That is what I expected as well, so I was very surprised when I gained one more many turns later. Although I admit I assumed it was due to "Enticing" and didn't investigate it further at that time.  I guess we need some more experimenting to settle this.

Comment: Hmm. Perhaps more testing is merited.

Comment: @RavenDreamer Updated my answer to reflect my current understanding. You were right: starbases are one-time only. I was confused by a planets converting, but this can be done without Enticing.